# Class 'Memcache' not found in

Tags: memcached

Moved to the site hosting from Network Solutions, the error occurred

**Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in / data / ... / include / connect.inc on line 6**

How can I fix it? I created a php.ini file in the folder cgi bin, added there the line **extension = "memcache.so"**. But apparently the module itself is not on the server. What should I do? Hosted by usual, is not VPS.

*Sorry for my English :)*

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `phpinfo()` output to identify where the `php.ini` file is and whether the Memcache module is loaded.

If the server is not managed by you then you might have problems getting this PECL module installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `php -m | grep memcached` to check whether memcached.so is loaded successfully. 
 - If show `memcached`, this mean it succeeded.
 - Else it is not loaded
Or check phpinfo, see whether there is a Memcached SectionL like this
[image]

if `php -m | grep memcached` shows:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0

Here is the solusion:
e.g your php.ini is /etc/php.ini, your php.d is /etc/php.d/

**Solution 1**

1. comment 'memcached.so' in php.ini
2. `vim /etc/php.d/memcached.ini`
3. add `extension=memcached.so` in /memcached.ini
4. `php -m | grep memcached` check whether memcached is succeed loaded

**Solution 2**

1. `rm /etc/php.d/json.ini`
2. add `extension=json.so` in php.in before `extension=memcached.so`
3. `php -m | grep memcached` check whether memcached is succeed loaded